# Programmatically login to web page HTTPS (C#)

Tags: authentication, https, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to login programmatically to a web page and I'm having any joy. I had a look at fiddler to see what the browser is doing but I'm struggling to replicate it in code.
Here is the code so far.

```
private void VisitUrl()
{
    string pageVisited = string.Empty;
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    //Go to login page so that we get a cookie
    HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.apage.com/login.asp");

    loginRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    loginRequest.UserAgent = Constants.usrAgentIE8;
    loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    loginRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    HttpWebResponse loginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse();

    string guid = Regex.Match(loginResponse.Headers["Set-Cookie"], Constants.guidRegex).Value;
    guid = guid.Replace("%2D", "-");

    //Now that we have the cookie we can do a proper login
    HttpWebRequest doLogin = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://secure.apage.com/express/login.asp");

    //doLogin.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    doLogin.UserAgent = Constants.usrAgentIE8;
    doLogin.Method = Constants.verbPOST;
    doLogin.ContentType = Constants.contTypeURLenc;
    doLogin.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(doLogin.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        sw.Write("usr=user&pass=" + Constants.pass + "&mc=1&guid=" + guid + "&dbnum=0&ic=1&task=dologin&app=library&x=32&y=10");

    }

    doLogin.CookieContainer = cookies;
    doLogin.Referer = "http://www.apage.com/login.asp";

    HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)doLogin.GetResponse();

    string resphead = Response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

    string resp = Response.StatusCode.ToString();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string textresponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.apage.com/toc.aspx?id=40729");
    Request.UserAgent = Constants.usrAgentIE8;
    Request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    Request.CookieContainer = cookies;

    using (HttpWebResponse urlResponse = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(urlResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageVisited = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I try the third request, http://www.apage.com/toc.aspx?id=40729, it is just missing a cookie, and it seems me back to the login page. This is a successful login with a browser from fiddler:

```
 1  200 HTTP    CONNECT secure.apage.com:443    0           iexplore:5908           
 2  200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/login.asp  3,253   private     text/html   iexplore:5908           
 3  200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/zarketing.css  13,340      text/css    iexplore:5908           
 4  200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/images/_loadingtext.gif    798     image/gif   iexplore:5908           
 5  200 HTTP    CONNECT secure.apage.com:443    0           iexplore:5908           
 6  200 HTTP    CONNECT secure.apage.com:443    0           iexplore:5908           
 7  200 HTTP    CONNECT secure.apage.com:443    0           iexplore:5908           
 8  200 HTTP    CONNECT secure.apage.com:443    0           iexplore:5908           
 9  200 HTTP    CONNECT secure.apage.com:443    0           iexplore:5908           
 10 200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/images/_loadingbox1.gif    66      image/gif   iexplore:5908           
 11 200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/images/_loadingbox5.gif    66      image/gif   iexplore:5908           
 12 200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/images/_loadingbox4.gif    100     image/gif   iexplore:5908           
 13 200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/images/_loadingbox2.gif    66      image/gif   iexplore:5908           
 14 200 HTTPS   secure.apage.com    /express/images/_loadingbox3.gif    66      image/gif   iexplore:5908           
 15 302 HTTP    www.apage.com   /authenticate.asp?ticket=2ECCC1686F49BE35E14556E76EFCBF3E478157F89B826A03C421883BE61BB634D8DDDB25F8943414252CE46C27B1FAE837B802A7BD1EE9723ECDCB99B7D3D1DB60FAB3042D0D632BF1C41BA622C2546E&mc=1  142 max-age=0, no-cache, no-store  Expires: Fri, 10 Jun 2011 09:04:21 GMT   text/html   iexplore:5908           
 16 200 HTTP    www.apage.com   /toc.aspx?id=40729  86,179  max-age=0, no-cache, no-store  Expires: Fri, 10 Jun 2011 09:04:22 GMT   text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:5908
```

Request 15 is a redirect and this request already has the missing cookie, but I don't know how this cookie is created. It does not seem to be present on response from my second request, https://secure.apage.com/express/login.asp , I've looked while debugging.

Do I need to make requests for all the gifs?

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading. if port 80 is not open the program is useless. the tile should be "Programatically login to web page HTTPS through HTTP (c#)"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
doLogin.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

The HTTP status code 302 (line 15) shows that a file has been 'temporarily moved'. You may need to allow redirects.

Also, cookie information can also be passed in the `Headers` collection property. Look in the response's `Headers.Keys` collection for any name like 'cookie'. For example, the website I have to log into uses the name 'Set-Cookie'. I get the value like so:

```
if (response.Headers["Set-Cookie"] != null)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(response.Headers["Set-Cookie"].ToString(), @"(?'Name'\w+)
=(?'Value'\w+).+=(?'Path'[\s\S]+)");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(match.Groups["Name"].ToString(), 
match.Groups["Value"].ToString(), match.Groups["Path"].ToString(), "domain.name.com");
        cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I have tried the setting allowautoredirect to true to no avail, though. I might give it another whirl when I get some time.

Comment: The 302 status code may well be nothing to do with it, but did you check the HTTP headers collection for the cookie information?